# Can I load an external file into table for LT spice?

Tags: ltspice

I would like to load a table (for `table` instead of editing the table manually) into LT spice, but it's very large (180x2 items). Is there a way that I can load a table into LT spice from an external file?

(I know I can load a PWL file from a csv into a voltage source, that isn't what I want to do, I want to do interpolation from a table)

Comment: Is your table a `.csv` file, or similar? LTspice can only import simple pairs of numbers. Extension doesn't matter.

Comment: It's nebulous right now, I can make it any format I want

Comment: Can you give an example of a few pairs of data as input and a draw or some other suggestive description of how the output data should be? What sort of interpolation do you expect? Linear, quadratic, fleur de lis?

Comment: Thermistor data, there isn't a high fidelity way to convert from temperature to resistance with good numerical accuacy, the Stienhart-hart equations are not good for this especially the inverse equations.

Comment: Then, if linear basic interpolation is acceptable, LTspice will do with a PWL. Do you intend to export the interpolated data? As in use LTspice as in intermediary, only? Because other interpolations may be better (Octave's `interp1()` comes to mind).

Comment: I want to generate a PWL file and then have LT spice do the interpolation between two sets of data with a table, so I want to do interp1 in LT spice. I'm thinking `table` will do that for me?

Comment: I think you can load WAV files.

Comment: I know you can load wav files into a pwl table, but I don't think you can for a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the contents of the file has time-value pairs separated by comma or spaces, with or without newline (be it Linux/Unix, Mac, or Windows), it doesn't matter what extension it has. The pairs may or may not be enclosed within parenthesis. The time values must be incremental.

Examples of valid files:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
...
```

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
...
```

```
1 2, 3
4, 5 6
...
```

```
1 2 3 ,4 5 , 6 ...
```

```
(1 2) (3, 4),(+0.1 -20) ...
```

All these will work. The spaces and commas are mostly as delimiters, their position doesn't seem to matter much (there may be exceptions, some caution applies). Don't forget that if there are sharp edges, instead of writing (e.g.) `12m 3 12.000001m 4` it's easier to use the relative increment `12m 3 +1n 4`. The minus (`-`) is also available, but only for the values. As far as I know, there is no limit to the file size except your memory (I've worked with tens of thousands of pairs, it was relatively slow, but it worked). Also, it's not limited to `PWL()`, `FREQ()` triplets are also welcome.

---

`table()` can also be used, but a different approach is needed. By itself, it has no option to load external data, but it can be used as a SPICE netlist:

```
B1 out 0 v=table(   ; or VCVS, VCCS, etc
+ <data-data pairs>  ; '+' is needed to concatenate the lines
+ ...
)
```

This can be placed in a new file, then included in the schematic with `.inc /path/to/some.file`, or the extra lines can be appended to the already existent file with data. The advantage is that `table()` is not restricted to strictly increasing increments for the first elements in the data pairs. The disadvantage is the more cumbersome way of loading it. `table()`, too, has only linear interpolation.

Comment: My question has more to do with how do you call the external file and treat it as a table? I'd like to do interpolation from a file

Comment: The usual `PWL file=/path/to/filename.bla` will do (or `wavefile=...` for `.wav` files, limited to +/- 1). But if what you want is to load the file and rely on LTspice to apply some interpolation other than a simple linear fit, you will be disappointed; linear is the only one it knows. If you want the quadratic interpolation available for the FFT, it will not be visible to the user, it's only applied internally before FFT. But, if linear is what you want, that's the way to go. You may or may not need `.opt plotwinsize=0`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the more cumbersome `table()`. When you said table I thought you meant a spreadsheet.

Comment: So it isn't possible, I didnt' think it was, sounds like it's time for a feature request.

Comment: I wish you good luck, no sarcasm, but I doubt they'll implement it. At any rate, Octave may be more fruitful for this task.

Comment: I already have a matlab script, but it's hard to do the noise calculations and compare circuits\amps ect, if you could do interpolation directly in lt spice that would open up a lot of possibilities for sensor simulations.